# Handing Get/{id} vs Get/id with flurl

Tags: c#, get, asp.net-core-mvc, flurl

I'm trying to get `Flurl` to work and I'm stuck on how gets work when passing in an ID.

```
[HttpGet("Get/{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    // Some something and return
}
```

The above expects

```
Get/1
```

So in Flurl:

```
var result = await _baseUrl
    .AppendPathSegment("/Get")
    .SetQueryParam("id", id)
    .GetJsonAsync();
```

This produces this:

```
/Get?id=8
```

...which then fails with a 404.

How can I get Flurl to set a query param that is /id or get my get to accept both Get/id and Get?id=

I can do the following but it doesn't seem very elegant

```
var result = await _baseUrl
    .AppendPathSegment(string.Format("/Get/{0}", id))
    .GetJsonAsync();
```

Comment: I've not used Flurl, but I am guessing that `SetQueryParam` will set a querystring, but you are building a path. Can you do `_baseUrl.AppendPathSegments("get", id.ToString())`?

Comment: @DavidG I can, no need for the .ToString. That was simple! Add an answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetQueryParam` will add the value as a query string but you need the value to be part of the path. Instead consider using the `AppendPathSegments` method, for example:

```
var result = _baseUrl
    .AppendPathSegments("get", id)
    .GetJsonAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:

```
var result = "https://api.site.com/v1/".AppendPathSegment("endpoint").AppendPathSeparator().SetQueryParam("get", id)
// Outputs: "https://api.site.com/v1/endpoint/?get=5"
```

Comment: OP specifically doesn't want a query string though.